# How do I add a certificate to an SFTP site running on OpenSSH on Windows Server 2019?

Tags: ssh, sftp, windows-server-2019

I have an SFTP site running on OpenSSH on Windows Server 2019. I can log in to it with a Windows username and password, but I want to also enable logging in with an SSL certificate. So I created a key (the default type of RSA, with the default 2048 bits) using PuTTYgen, but I'm having trouble installing it. I've been searching around online for how to do this, and I found two possibilities:

1. Append the public key to the C:\users\Administrator\.ssh\authorized_keys file.
2. Add the public and private keys as individual files to the C:\ProgramData\ssh folder.

However neither of these options works; I keep getting "access denied" when I try to log in with the private key.

Do I need to restart one or both of the OpenSSH services on the server after installing a key? I'd try that but I'm not sure if they're used by anything else, so even though I'm working with a test server right now I'm a bit hesitant to do that...

Or do I need to generate a key while logged in as the user on the server I want to log in with the key as? (As opposed to generating the key locally and copying it to the server)